# How do I write my dtaframe having very large text in each row to excel, without skipping any character?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a (Pandas) dataframe, in which each row has very big paragraph. Each row may have more than 200 words also. Not sure what is the highest number of words in that. When I am printing it to excel using to_excel() method, it is not printing after some words. I think it is because, the paragraph is too huge to write in excel. That's why, I guess it is not able to write whole text to excel.

Is there any solution for this? Can I print whole paragraph to the cells of excel file, without skipping any characters or words?

[I am using Python 3 in jupyter notebook]

Comment: An Excel cell can contain up to [32,767 characters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). Are you hitting that limit? Please create a [reprex].

Comment: Can you please post a snippet of your code and, if possible, a picture of your data frame?

Comment: Try pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 5)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.